# How to format print string to 2 decimal places as well as right aligning each set of values

Tags: python, pandas

Once the user selects a colchoice to view the statistics for a given column. I would like to print the output line by line, also to 2 decimal places and get each row to align properly. How can I go about this?

```
import pandas as pd 
import os

data = {'first':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'second':[34,23,12,56,76,23,123, 19], 'third':[123,34,2,45,56,76,324,23]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data)

def analyse_data(data):
    colchoice = input("Please select a column to analyse: ")
    while True:
        if colchoice in data:
            print(f"{colchoice} \n--------\n number of values(n):\t {data[colchoice].count()} \n minimum value:\t {data[colchoice].min()}\n maximum value:\t {data[colchoice].max()}\n mean: \t {data[colchoice].mean()}\n median: \t {data[colchoice].median()}\n standard deviation: \t  {data[colchoice].std()} \n std.error. of mean: \t {data[colchoice].sem()}",  sep=os.linesep)
            break
        else:
            print("Please try again")
            colchoice = input("Please select a column to analyse: ")
            
        
            

analyse_data(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the format documentation here -- https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

There are examples for aligning and padding lines.

```py
>>> print("This is: {:>10.2f}".format(45.2343))
This is:      45.23
```

Comment: How do I do it with so many {inputs}. Do I need to do it for each one or is there something I can do to format in the one way overall? so like :>10.2f for all as opposed to df.min():.>10.2f, df.max():>10.2f etc etc.

Comment: @LucasBlatchford You would do the formatting for each one.